# Undefined index when post information from form to xampp

Tags: php, html

These are my codes
I keep having the undefined index from the php side, but i think i already clearly post the right information from the form side, but still...
Help me PLS!!! Help me PLS!!! Help me PLS!!! Help me PLS!!! Help me PLS!!!

```
<form class="modal-content animate" action="TenantSdb.php">
<div class="container">
  <label><b>Username</b></label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required>

  <label><b>Password</b></label>
  <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>

  <label><b>Email address</b></label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required>

  <label><b>Contact No</b></label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Contact" name="contact_no" required>

  <label><b>Looking for which area</b></label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Area" name="area" required>

  <label><b>Gender</b></label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Gender" name="gender" required>

  <label><b>Age</b></label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Age" name="age" required>

  <label><b>Max Budget</b></label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Budget" name="max_budget" required>

  <label><b>Staying With</b></label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Staying with" name="staying_with"
  required>

  <label><b>Race</b></label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Race" name="race" required>



  <button type="submit">Sign Up</button>
  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked"> Remember me
</form>
</div>
```

`

```
$servername ="localhost";
$dbusername ="root";
$dbpassword ="";
$dbname = "tenantsdb";

$uname          =   $_POST['uname'];
$psw            =   $_POST['psw'];
$email          =   $_POST['email'];
$contact_no     =   $_POST['contact_no'];
$area           =   $_POST['area'];
$gender         =   $_POST['gender'];
$age            =   $_POST['age'];
$max_budget     =   $_POST['max_budget'];
$staying_with   =   $_POST['staying_with'];
$race           =   $_POST['race'];


$conn = new mysqli($servername, $dbusername,$dbpassword, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error)
{
die("Connection failed : " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql   = "INSERT INTO tenantsignup 
(uname,psw,email,contact_no,area,gender,max_budget,staying_with,race) VALUES 

('$uname','$psw','$email','$contact_no','$area','$gender','$max_budget',
'$staying_with','$race')";

if($conn->query($sql) === TRUE)
{
echo "Thank you !";
}

else
{
echo "error" . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}



$conn->close();



?> 

i am getting undefined index from 
$uname          =   $_POST['uname'];
$psw            =   $_POST['psw'];
$email          =   $_POST['email'];
$contact_no     =   $_POST['contact_no'];
$area           =   $_POST['area'];
$gender         =   $_POST['gender'];
$age            =   $_POST['age'];
$max_budget     =   $_POST['max_budget'];
$staying_with   =   $_POST['staying_with'];
$race           =   $_POST['race'];


Keep gettting undefined index ^^^ from top, can anyone tell me the problem ?
Please help me, thank you very much
```

Answer (score 0):

You have specify the attribute `method='POST'`

```
<form class="modal-content animate" action="TenantSdb.php" method="POST">
```

The default method is `GET`. SO if you do not specify method you could access it only by using `$_GET`

Comment: yeah, correct...i have change to method = "post", and it worked...thank you very much :)

Comment: @PerryPuah Happy coding...!

Comment: thanks @Harikrishnan N

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the method otherwise default will be **GET** method. In case if you don't know what exactly method is using in form then you use $_REQUEST. $_REQUEST can **POST** data as well as **GET** data. It works for both.